# mistake in the database access: SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: android

I really can't seem to figure out the mistake I made in the database below.

The error message I get is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hamroschool.hamroschool/com.hamroschool.activitypages.Exams}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Class (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Result_type, Class, Exam_Type, Date, Marks_Sheet, Full_Marks, Obtained_Marks, Comments, CGPA FROM Exams
```

My database schema is as follows:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXAMS + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                +"Result_type TEXT"
                + "Class TEXT,"
                + "Exam_Type TEXT,"
                + "Date TEXT,"
                + "Marks_Sheet TEXT,"
                + "Full_Marks TEXT,"
                + "Obtained_Marks TEXT,"
                + "Comments TEXT,"
                + "CGPA TEXT);");
```

and I am using the following piece of code to access the database

```
SQLiteDatabase db = open();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Exams",
                new String[]{"_id","Result_type","Class",
                        "Exam_Type", "Date", "Marks_Sheet", "Full_Marks",
                        "Obtained_Marks", "Comments","CGPA",},
                null,
                null, null, null, null
        );
```

I am getting error while the code reaches the cursor.

Comment: The error points to the class column not being found. Have you recently added that column? If you have then try deleting the app off of your device and reinstalling

Comment: i have done that numerous time but no luck

Comment: remove "," (comma) after CGPA, you have written "CGPA", and you forgot to put comma in create table query  +"Result_type TEXT,"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake in create table query

You missed **comma** after Result_type column.

Your **Query** should be like this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXAMS + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                +"Result_type TEXT, "
                + "Class TEXT, "
                + "Exam_Type TEXT, "
                + "Date TEXT, "
                + "Marks_Sheet TEXT, "
                + "Full_Marks TEXT, "
                + "Obtained_Marks TEXT, "
                + "Comments TEXT, "
                + "CGPA TEXT);");
```